# How to estimate the cost of updating one column and Updating 100 column in Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Please tell me how to estimate the cost of updating one column and Updating 100 column in Oracle database?
I am using form submission strategy. when I save the form and update I use the form submission in this approach, when I am updating one column all columns is updated again. How to resolve this issue in generic way and how to estimate the cost?

Comment: Why does this matter to you?

Comment: "In generic way" is a big no-no. Questions asked on this site must be specific, you must ask for help on a specific issue or problem with code you have written. Then: Are you asking to estimate the "cost" that the Oracle cost-based optimizer uses? I believe that is proprietary (a commercial secret of Oracle), so the question really doesn't make sense.

Comment: If your table has 100 columns, then you probably have a design issue, that you should fix. Updating several columns vs. only updating the dirty ones is possible, but it most probably won't make things faster. It will probably even make them slower (no prepared statement reuse, dirty checking, etc.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to increase performance of my project . some one suggest me to update specific column only .

Comment: @mathguy I need to increase performance of my project please do need full  please help me so i can improve .

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the reply. can you tell me how to design the form so that performance will improve

Comment: Are you sure they suggested updating specific **columns** only, and not specific **rows** only? If they really said specific **columns** you are probably safe ignoring their advice - it makes no sense.

Comment: thank you  @mathguy